# Register Com-Interop for .net windows service

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, com-interop

Is it possible to register a vb.net Service for com-interop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no (the clue to this is the fact that the 'Register for COM Interop' checkbox is greyed out on a windows service), but the question is what do you think you would achieve by doing this?

Comment: I have a mainprogramm written in vb6 and tools using shared dll. my services manages(starts, stops, configures,...) the tools on a server. when updating the mainprogramm, i have to be sure, all tools are closed, so i need to communicate from vb6 installer to the service....

Comment: Your solution is probably to use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) then